# Задача на массив в питоне

Tags: python, массивы, list

Дан массив, например, M = [3,8,2,4] . Как узнать равна ли сумма каких-нибудь двух его элементов числу 12?

[image: Я пыталась так сделать,но выдает ошибку]

Comment: Что за ужас у вас тут на скрине? ))

Comment: отчаянные попытки,я полагаю

Comment: Вы хотя бы разберитесь, что у вас в `i` для начала

Comment: разве это не элементы массива?

Comment: Нет. Что такое 0[0] по вашему?

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте так:

```
def f(arr):
    for el in arr:
        if 12 - el in arr:
             print(el, 12 - el)
```

также по совету Zhihar можно использовать множество

```
def f(arr):
    arr = set(arr)
    for el in arr:
        if 12 - el in arr:
             print(el, 12 - el)
```

Comment: если предварительно список превратить в множество, то работать будет еще быстрее для больших списков

Comment: не могли бы вы на пальцах объяснить

Answer (score 2):

Берем все комбинации по 2 элемента и суммируем. Потом с помощью `any` проверяем есть ли хоть одно истинное значение в списке.

```
from itertools import combinations

M = [3, 8, 2, 4]  
print(any(map(lambda x: sum(x) == 12, combinations(M, 2)))) # True
```

Comment: `list` не нужен, `any` и так нормально `map` проитерирует )

Comment: Неоптимально же.

Comment: @Эникейщик, благодарен питону за то, что можно мысли сразу воплощать в код. Не благодарен за то, что это не заставляет обдумывать решение. P.S. уклон был на однострочное решение :)

Answer (score 1):

Я как обычно добавлю чисто функциональный вариант, хотя с лямбдой было бы и короче:

```
from itertools import combinations
from operator import eq
from functools import partial

M = [3, 8, 2, 4]  
print(any(map(partial(eq, 12), map(sum, combinations(M, 2)))))
```

Хотя на самом деле можно и без лямбды и без лишних библиотек (но как бы с циклом):

```
from itertools import combinations

M = [3, 8, 2, 4]  
print(any(sum(x) == 12 for x in combinations(M, 2)))
```

Comment: парни, спасибо всем, кто написал ответ. Но есть дополнительный вопрос: ведь решение с двумя вложенными циклами (а, как я понимаю, все приведенные решения сводятся к этому) - это не особо оптимальное решение. Мне кажется, оно работает за N x N. Нет ли здесь решения получше? буду благодарен за подсказку. я пока вижу только один более оптимальный - как мне кажется - алгоритм: для каждого элемента массива запускаем двоичный поиск пары, которая меньше всего отличается от требуемой суммы. тогда понадобится N x log(N) операций

Answer (score 0):

ну тут только методом перебора

потребуется 2 цикла - первый пройдет с первого элемента до предпоследнего, а второй (вложенный в первый) со следующего от текущего для первого цикла элемента до последнего

складываем 2 элемента из 2 циклов и сравниваем

```
M = [3,8,2,4]

for i in range(len(M) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(M)):
        if M[i] + M[j] == 12:
            print(f"{M[i]} + {M[j]} = 12")
```

ну или в однострочном варианте:

```
res = [(M[i], M[j]) for i in range(len(M) - 1) for j in range(i + 1, len(M)) if M[i] + M[j] == 12]
```

это самый быстрый вариант, можно немного поизвращаться и использовать библиотечную функцию - сгенерировать уникальные пары из массива и искать среди них суммы - но это дольше

Comment: Вон выше с одним циклом.

Comment: да, у @Danis мне решение понравилось, только там все равно O(n^2) сидит, если переделать список в множество тогда будет O(nlog(n)) и это уже очень хорошо